# MILP Minimum set Vertex cover coding by Python or MATLAB?

Tags: python, cplex, matlab

As a following up for my question for modeling a simple moded of the minimum set vertex cover problem, which is shown next. I would like to have your help in modeling this problem using Python or MATLAB. I believe that each edge with its origin vertex and destination vertex as a binary variable will solve the problem. I'm a little confused about how this variable will represent both vertices.
The problem can be shown as graph $G=(V,E)$ where we want to:
$$
\min \quad \sum_{v\in V} x_v
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_u + x_v &\ge 1 \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E \\
\sum_{(u,v)\in E} z_{uv} &\ge k \\
z_{uv} &\le x_v \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E\\
z_{uv} &\le 1-x_u \quad &\forall (u,v) \in E\\
x_v&\in \{0,1\} \quad &\forall v \in V\\
z_{uv} &\in \{0,1\}\quad &\forall (u,v) \in E
\end{align}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, with [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp) and [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) :

```
import pulp 
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
# define your graph here
#...


# define the problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem("MinimumSetVertexCover", pulp.LpMinimize)

# define the variables
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", G.nodes(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)
z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("z", G.edges(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)

# define the objective function
prob += pulp.lpSum(x)

# define the constraints
for (u,v) in G.edges():
    prob += x[u] + x[v] >= 1
    prob += z[(u,v)] <= x[v]
    prob += z[(u,v)] <= 1-x[u]
prob += pulp.lpSum(z) >= k

# solve
prob.solve()

# display objective function value
print("number of vertices in solution : %s"%pulp.prob.objective.value())

# display solution
for v in G.nodes():
    if pulp.value(x[v]) > 0.9:
         print("node %s selected"%v)
```

I suggest you

1. Check out pulp's [examples](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/index.html) to understand the syntax
2. Do not just copy paste the above answer if you want to learn something

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Please help here (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege) in re here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095760/is-optimal-solution-to-dual-not-unique-if-optimal-solution-to-the-primal-is-dege)

Comment: @Amedeo Kuifje helped me a lot before too.

Comment: Sorry but what is k?

Comment: A given parameter.